# Attach file to data row

Tags: attachment, acumatica

I am trying to attach a text file to a data row in my custom object.  I must be missing something. I have the pointer to the current record (asn) and the Byte array (retLabels.Labels) but I can't figure out what the third parameter should be.  Also, do I need to execute an update and save after attaching the file?

```
if (retLabels.Code == "OK" || ediDemo)
{
    asnGraph.ASN.Current = asn;
    PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(asn, retLabels.Labels, ???? PX.SM.FileInfo );
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might need the file saved to Acumatica first as a FileInfo object. Does this post help any: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065356/upload-images-to-serial-number based on the use of FileInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file in memory:

```
PX.SM.FileInfo file = new PX.SM.FileInfo("textfile.txt", 
                                         null,
                                         Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Text file content."));
```

Upload the file in Acumatica:

```
UploadFileMaintenance upload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

upload.SaveFile(file, 
                FileExistsAction.CreateVersion);
```

Attach the file to any DAC records by linking file UID (unique ID) to DAC NoteID field:

```
PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)], dacRecord, file.UID.Value);
```