# File upload and attach in Acumatica

Tags: file, attachment, acumatica

I'm actually new in Acumatica Framework. I'm having some issues to understand how to attach the file. The problem is that in this answer [Attach file to data row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508669/attach-file-to-data-row) they talk about

> PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)], dacRecord, file.UID.Value);

I do not understand what do they refer about "Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)], dacRecord", I've already saved the file but the step of setting the file is my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the Cache object corresponding to the type of your Record and the Record itself. For example if you need to attach file to `SOOrder` you will provide values like below:

```
var currentSOOrder = soOrderEntry.Document.Current;
PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(soOrderEntry.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)], currentSOOrder , file.UID.Value);
```

Comment: Thans a lot! You saved me =)